# how to pass a ndb key with a parent and use it to get an entity

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, key, app-engine-ndb, ancestor

I pass an NDB Key() with a parent to a deferred function. In this function I retrieve the entity again. But I cannot use the passed key to get the entity directly. I have to change the key order pairing in the ndb.Key().

```
deferred.defer(my_deferred.a_function, entity.key)
```

The entity.key() looks like :

```
Key('Parents', 'my_parent', 'Childs', 'my_child')    # the first pair is the parent?
```

my_deferred.py :

```
def a_function(key) :

    entity = ndb.Key(key)  # the pass entity.key does not work !!!!!
```

Giving exception : ValueError: Key() must have an even number of positional arguments.

```
    entity = ndb.Key('Childs', key.id(), parent = key.parent()).get() # this one works fine
```

I do not understand why the entity.key() method does not give me a key, which I can use directly? Or is there another way to get the entity, without "changing" the key. And I do not understand the ValueError excpetion.

**Update** : Thanks to Gregory

```
    entity = key.get()    # works fine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, answering your code specific question, passing the key properly, it is not a callable:

`deferred.defer(my_deferred.a_function, entity.key)`

next, on the actual design of the code itself, there are some things that need tweaking.

- the deferred api serializes your code, so there really is no need to re-query entity from the datastore. if you insist on this though, passing the `entity.key` to the deferred method, it's already an instance of `ndb.Key`, so there's no need to construct a new Key object.

Comment: Tahnks for your answer. Sorry, I mistyped entity.key() in my question (not in my code) and changed it to entity.key. I once read : never pass an entity to a task. But if I pass the key, only the key. And when I pass entity.key I cannot use the key directly, because the first pair of the key holds the parent.

Comment: Reading your answer again. I tried: key.get(). Yes, this works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but what about:

```
entity = ndb.Key(*key.flat())
```

The `Key` constructor accepts a few different kinds of input, and since `flat()` [Returns a tuple of flattened kind and id values (kind1, id1, kind2, id2, ...).](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors), unpacking the tuple should pass in the necessary inputs . Per the same link, this should also work:

```
entity = ndb.Key(pairs=key.pairs())
```

Comment: Though this works, it is nonsensical to do so. He already has the key, so doesn't need to construct a new one.

Comment: @bossylobster True, did feel a bit funky - I voted for the other answer anyway :)

Comment: The problem is : I have the key, but I have to create a new key from this key, because the key is not accepted.